# flashbuilder 4.5 mobile no com.adobe.fiber

Tags: ios, flash-builder4.5

I have a `Flashbuilder-project` and converting it for `iOS`.

But I get an error at :

```
import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
import com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.HTTPServiceWrapper;
```

cant find these libraries.

Answer (score 2):

add the following libraries in your project.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.6.1.335153\fiberSwcs\4.5\libs\fiber.swc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.6.1.335153\fiberSwcs\4.5\locale\fiber_rb.swc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.6.1.335153\fiberSwcs\4.5\libs\playerfds.swc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.6.1.335153\dcradSwcs\4.5\libs\serializers.swc
```

Answer (score 1):

File name: `fiber.swc`

You can find this packages in [Adobe LiveCycle Data Services](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/)